# Improving performance of a query

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following sql query Performing badly:

```
SELECT 
    Count(ExtCardID) as CardCount 
from 
    CardIDs CARDS with (NoLock)
inner join 
    (select CustomerPK 
     from GroupMembership with (NoLock)
     where CustomerGroupID = 14 and Deleted = 0) as GM on GM.CustomerPK = CARDS.CustomerPK
```

The following `Select` part from the above join returned 8 million records:

```
select 
    CustomerPK from GroupMembership with (NoLock)
where 
    CustomerGroupID = 14 and Deleted = 0
```

Is there a better way to write the above sql code? Please advise.

Comment: What indexes do you have in place? Can you post the execution plan?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with LINQ?

LINQ is quite good rather than direct query!

[Great Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26431/Performance-Comparisons-LINQ-to-SQL-ADO-C)